Problem sorting by date column with specific timezone in SQLAlchemy
I'm working on a Flask application with SQLAlchemy as ORM and PostgreSQL as the database. In my model, I have a date column stored in UTC timezone (DB Server Time):
class Auditoria(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'auditoria'
    fecha = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())

I need to sort the results of a query according to this date column, but I want the sorting to be done in the user's timezone, not in UTC. I've tried using func.timezone() in the order_by() clause, but it seems that it's not applying the timezone conversion correctly, as I still get the dates in UTC.
return db.session.query(Auditoria).order_by(func.timezone(user_time_zone, Auditoria.fecha)).all()

(Note that user_time_zone is a TZ saved in the DB, like 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'
Using pure SQL has the same effect:
SELECT *
FROM Auditoria
ORDER BY fecha AT TIME ZONE (SELECT nombre from timezones where timezones.id = 1) ;

After doing quite a bit of research, the only way I could figure out to get both func.timezone() and AT TIME ZONE to work in SQL is to generate a new column where the time zone conversion is effectively applied, as this:
SELECT id, fecha AT TIME ZONE (SELECT nombre from timezones where timezones.id = 1) as fecha_local
FROM Auditoria;

The problem is that I want to obtain the entire model object without modifying (adding columns).
Is there any way to achieve this in SQLAlchemy without getting a new column with the modified date?
For the record, a new column would mean more logic after getting the query, modifying Marshmallow schemas, and preparing the Front End to receive that new date, things I'd rather avoid
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

just for my understanding, how does sorting with a timezone change things? the earliest time will be at the start and the latest will be at the end, so what change in behavior does it bring?

@python_user The difference will be that not only will it do the sorting, but it will show the DateTime column with the user's time zone.
